# calculus problem involving integration and mean value theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

http://people.math.sc.edu/girardi/m555/current/hw/MVT-Flett.pdf
the first question of this pdf

$g(x)$ is a continous function in $[a,b]$ and  $ g(a)=0$,      $\int_a^b g(t) \ dt=0$

to prove there exit $ c\in (a,b) $ such that     $g(c)(c-a)=\int_a^cg(t) \ dt$

I did manage to write down the prove I dont know whether thats correct or not,anyways my solution is not elegant I worked with couple of cases and used method of contradiction along with  WLOG , which doesnot look pretty.

I looking for a more elegant solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the linked paper it is indicated to consider

$$\varphi(x) = \frac{\int_a^xg(t) dt}{x-a} \text{ where } \varphi(a) = g(a) = 0$$

Now, according to the assumptions you have

$$\varphi(a) = \varphi(b)= 0$$ and you can apply Rolle theorem. So, there is a $c \in (a,b)$ such that

$$\varphi'(c) = \frac{g(c)(c-a)-\int_a^cg(t) dt}{(c-a)^2}= 0$$

From this your claim follows immediately.